# Is anyone able to send currencyCode with Analytics.js transaction tag inside GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, analytics.js

I'd first like to present two exhibits:

The official documentation for

- tracking e-commerce [using analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)
- tracking e-commerce [using analytics.js inside of GTM](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3002596?hl=en)

Now then, what is pertinent here is the former makes mention of a currency field while the latter does not.

Thus far I have been unable to cause GTM -> analytics.js to find and send the currency code along with the item hit or transaction hit.

I have tried:

- Doing the analytics.js method inside of a custom HTML tag type

  - no events were fired at all
- Doing the GTM method with a 'currency' field added to the item object, a 'transactionCurrency' field in the transaction object;

  - the transaction and item hits are sent without currency info
- calling ga( 'set' , 'currencyCode', 'CAD' ) from inside my GTM tag before the transaction and item are fired

I am out of ideas to try. Anyone with a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Universal Analytics tag template set to transaction and a custom field "currencyCode" in "Fields to set". This works for me.

Comment: I need to set the value programmatically after combing the dataLayer. I'm going to try adding 'currencyCode' to the item and transaction.

Comment: I tried adding 'currencyCode' to the item and transaction, and it did not work, however setting the 'Fields to set' value to currencyCode and using a custom macro {{currencyCode}} worked! Thank you.